# How can I create an OSX readable image of an HFS+ disk mounted on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, macos, hfs+

I'm using Paragon HFS+ to read the drive which is plugged into an external SATA adaptor. What I would like to be able to do now is create a disk mage.

Can this be done in Windows? I've tried WinImage (which gets confused by HFS) and VMware converter, which simply seems confused by it all.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this from within Windows you'll need to do it through a bootable drive imager.

Have a look at [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/)